# Using Extjs4 in the frontend

Tags: model-view-controller, backbone.js, extjs4, frontend

I've been a big fan of BackboneJS (and still am) until I discover Extjs4 in my new Job. I can only tip my hat for what it can do! Now my question is whether it is possible (or recommanded) to use Extjs in the frontOffice without using its components. I only want to take advantage of both the MVC architecture that it offers and the module loader feature. With backbone, I use AMD and require Js for module loading and it's a pain and very hard to generate production build. 
I'm wondering also if Extjs will have a JavaScript routing engine in the next version.

Your advice will be very appreciated,
Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

1. Sound great that you are BackboneJS fan. To answer your question... You can use ExtJS anywhere in web application which makes end-user an real cutting-edge tech. You already worked in Backbone and learning ExtJS. First consider which one you need to use for your application, either BackboneJS or ExtJS, because both are advance concept of JS.
2. For your second question, ExtJS use well structured MVC pattern over BackboneJS. You dont need to migrate to ExtJS if you can able to create custom Controller(Getting components reference) control in BackboneJS. My suggestion is to go with ExtJS.
3. ExtJS sencha forum is really good one to learn more over their component reference and raise bugs and request for any new javascript routing engine as you mentioned.